# How to calculate the amplitude for emission of a gravitino in unbroken supersymmetry?

Tags: scattering, supersymmetry

I am studying supersymmetry and supergravity, and I have encountered the following problem:

Suppose that supersymmetry is unbroken. Show how to calculate the amplitude for emission of a gravitino of very low energy in a general scattering process in terms of the amplitude for this process without the gravitino.

I know that the gravitino is the superpartner of the graviton, and that it has spin-3/2 and mass zero in unbroken supersymmetry. I also know that there is a fermionic partner of the scalar field that breaks supersymmetry spontaneously, called the goldstino, which has spin-1/2 and mass zero.

I have heard of the goldstino equivalence theorem, which states that at energies much lower than the supersymmetry breaking scale, the longitudinal component of the gravitino field behaves like the goldstino field, and that its interactions are not suppressed by the Planck scale.

However, I am not sure how to apply this theorem to a general scattering process involving a gravitino of very low energy. How do I replace one of the external lines in the corresponding amplitude without the gravitino with a goldstino line? What is the kinematical factor that I need to multiply by? Where can I find more details about this calculation?